# execute clojure script in gradle

Tags: gradle, clojure, clojuresque

I've got project structure like this

```
functional-lore
    clojure-project
         src\main\clojure\com.lapots.functional.clojure
             script.clj
         build.gradle
build.gradle
```

Where root `build.gradle` looks like this

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "clojuresque:clojuresque-base:$clojuresqueVersion"
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://clojars.org/repo' }
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    group='com.lapots.functional'
}
```

And subproject `build.gradle` looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'clojure-min'

clojure {
    aotCompile = true
    warnOnReflection = true
}

repositories {
    clojarsRepo()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.clojure:clojure:$clojureVersion"
}
```

And I have simple `clojure` script `script.clj`

```
(ns com.lapots.functional.clojure.script)

(defn -main [& args]
      (println "Hello, world!"))
```

But how to run it with gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I went with that solution.
Added `:gen-class`.

```
(ns com.lapots.functional.clojure.script
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
      (println "Hello, world!"))
```

Created `gradle` task

```
task runClojure(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.lapots.functional.clojure.script'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

And then just ran it with `gradle runClojure`.